# MIME command for attaching multiple OTF & TTF Fonts to a video

Tags: fonts, mime-types, mime, truetype, opentype

I have a question about attaching fonts to a video (mkv). Usually, I use a `file.bat` to do the process of merging subtitles + attaching some specified fonts to my videos. This is the command line:

```
@echo off
for %%A IN (*.ass) do (
E:\Name\Mux\mkvmerge.exe -o "Output\%%~nA.mkv"  "--default-track" "0:yes" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--language" "1:jpn" "--default-track" "1:yes" "--forced-track" "1:no" "-a" "1" "-d" "0" "--no-attachments" "-S" "-T" "--no-global-tags" "(" "%%~nA.mkv" ")" "--language" "0:ara" "--track-name" "0:Arabic" "--default-track" "0:yes" "--forced-track" "0:yes" "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "--no-global-tags" "(" "%%~nA.ass" ")" "--track-order" "0:0,0:1,1:0" "--attachment-mime-type" "application/x-font-opentype" "--attachment-name" "AdobeArabic-Italic.otf" "--attach-file" "AdobeArabic-Italic.otf" "--attachment-name" "AdobeArabic-Bold.otf" "--attach-file" "AdobeArabic-Bold.otf" "--attachment-name" "AdobeArabic-Regular.otf" "--attach-file" "AdobeArabic-Regular.otf" "--attachment-name" "AdobeArabic-BoldItalic.otf" "--attach-file" "AdobeArabic-BoldItalic.otf"

echo  Done
)

pause
```

The problem is that I have to specify **every font I want to attach** in the command. What if I want to attach 20, 30 fonts? It's kind of a hassle to be honest to type them all. Not to mention that different subtitles have different fonts, so I have to modify the command every time!

Is there a command that can grab all fonts (TTF & OTF) that I put in a folder? So I can just replace the fonts in the directory.

Comment: That doesn't look like a complete command line since there's no command. Without knowing the full details, then, I'll suggest trying the FOR command within your bat file.

Comment: Why would you attach 30 full fonts? At that point you're basically guaranteed participating in typeface piracy, just using an .mkv as your archive format rather than .zip - are you subsetting based on the subs, first? Are you verifying what you can do with the font based on the fstype value? etc.